# how Ubuntu control fan

Tags: games, asus, fan

I have problem with my Asus fx504 and Ubuntu 19.10.
I had installed lm-sensors and use sensors-detect but when I use sensors my fan speed is 0 or -1:
asus-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
cpu_fan:       -1 RPM
how can solved this problem?
when I play game Ubuntu turns up my second fan but in normal using my laptop get hoter and hoter and I afraid to use Ubuntu instead Windows.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Could you follow the instruction here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingACPI#Fan_Issues and update the question as far you go, include all command output or upload long output to http://pastebin.ubuntu.com